# string modifications are not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-encoding

This is my code and in my url string white spaces are not encoded by the code

```
NSString *str  = item.fileArtPath;
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet];
[str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];
[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
```

for below string:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xx/xx/xx/xx/xxx/Audio Adrenaline.jpg
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The white space after `Audio` is not converted to `%20` after I used string replacement. And in Debugging `urlString` is `nil` why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the NSString Class Reference

> Returns a new string made from the receiver by replacing all
>   characters not in the specified set with percent encoded characters.

Meaning it doesn't permute the instance it's called on. You need to say something like `str = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];` Same with `[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];`

Answer (score 1):

Recall that `NSString` is *immutable*. Calling methods `stringBy...` returns the modified string, rather than modifying the original one. Therefore your code should be rewritten as follows:

```
str = [str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSString *search = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```